# Let $S$ be nonsingular size $n$ matrix. Show that the matrix $S^-1AS$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was thinking to go this way:
$|S^-1AS - LI|$ = $|S^-1AS - LS^-1S|$ = $|S^-1|$*$|AS - LS|$ = $|S^-1|$*$|A-LI|$*$|S|$ = $|A-LI|$

Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems right, although the notations are a bit confusing (and hard to read). Basically, the overall idea (and yours) is to write the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{S^{-1}A S}$ as
$$
\chi_{S^{-1}A S}(x) = \det(S^{-1}A S-xI) = \det(S^{-1}A S-xS^{-1}S)
= \det(S^{-1}(A-x I) S)
$$
and use the properties of the determinant with regard to multiplication (i.e., $\det(AB)=\det A\cdot\det B$) and inverse ($\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}$, implied by the previous property actually).

Comment: Yes. So, $det(A^-1) $= $1/det(A)$ right?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is invertible -- cf. second property I mentioned, which follows from $1 = \det I = \det(A A^{-1}) =  \det(A)\cdot \det(A^{-1})$.